# Regex which matches all contents between and including outer quotes if present, else entire text blob separated by un-escaped spaces

Tags: regex, bash, grep, parameter-passing

Although the question title is specifically about Regex, I would accept any solutions to the problem I explain in the question body

**Context:**

I have a script which passes on all of its parameters ($@) to another script once it has performed some actions on one of the arguments. The details are beyond the scope of this question but I am happy to discuss them in the comments section if necessary.

**What I am looking for:**

What I want is to be able to modify my regex (see below) so that I do not need to maintain a whitelist in the format: ...`(?= command1| command2| command3)`... *[edit:]* where `command*` can be any word at all

I want to be able to include the entire text blob passed to argument (-p, --project) including quotes if present into a new variable.

**Attempts:**

I have successfully constructed a regex that solves my immediate problem, [please view the explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/sc51bA/1). I think it explains my problem by way of examples.

Regex I constructed:

`(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)`

Test Strings:

```
pretend-cli -p /path\ to\ data/path/to/data01 command1 --some-other=123
pretend-cli -p "/path to data/path/to/data02" command2 --some-other=123
pretend-cli -p '/path to data/path/to/data03' command3 --some-other=123
pretend-cli -p=/path\ to\ data/path/to/data04 command1 --some-other=123
pretend-cli -p="/path to data/path/to/data05" command2 --some-other=123
pretend-cli -p='/path to data/path/to/data06' command3 --some-other=123
pretend-cli --project /path\ to\ data/path/to/data07 command1 --some-other=123
pretend-cli --project "/path to data/path/to/data08" command2 --some-other=123
pretend-cli --project '/path to data/path/to/data09' command3 --some-other=123
pretend-cli --project=/path\ to\ data/path/to/data10 command1 --some-other=123
pretend-cli --project="/path to data/path/to/data11" command2 --some-other=123
pretend-cli --project='/path to data/path/to/data12' command3 --some-other=123
```

But as you can see, it requires that I maintain a white-list.

**Further Explanation**

The way it would look in the current implementation of my script (12 isolated test cases):

```
PRETEND_PARAMETERS_01="-p /path\ to\ data/path/to/data01 command1 --some-other=123"
PRETEND_PARAMETERS_02="-p \"/path to data/path/to/data02\" command2 --some-other=123"
PRETEND_PARAMETERS_03="-p '/path to data/path/to/data03' command3 --some-other=123"
PRETEND_PARAMETERS_04="-p=/path\ to\ data/path/to/data04 command1 --some-other=123"
PRETEND_PARAMETERS_05="-p=\"/path to data/path/to/data05\" command2 --some-other=123"
PRETEND_PARAMETERS_06="-p='/path to data/path/to/data06' command3 --some-other=123"
PRETEND_PARAMETERS_07="--project /path\ to\ data/path/to/data07 command1 --some-other=123"
PRETEND_PARAMETERS_08="--project \"/path to data/path/to/data08\" command2 --some-other=123"
PRETEND_PARAMETERS_09="--project '/path to data/path/to/data09' command3 --some-other=123"
PRETEND_PARAMETERS_10="--project=/path\ to\ data/path/to/data10 command1 --some-other=123"
PRETEND_PARAMETERS_11="--project=\"/path to data/path/to/data11\" command2 --some-other=123"
PRETEND_PARAMETERS_12="--project='/path to data/path/to/data12' command3 --some-other=123"
```

The way I parse out the 'project path' from those parameters:

```
PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_01=$(grep -oP '(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)' <<< ${PRETEND_PARAMETERS_01})
PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_02=$(grep -oP '(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)' <<< ${PRETEND_PARAMETERS_02})
PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_03=$(grep -oP '(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)' <<< ${PRETEND_PARAMETERS_03})
PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_04=$(grep -oP '(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)' <<< ${PRETEND_PARAMETERS_04})
PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_05=$(grep -oP '(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)' <<< ${PRETEND_PARAMETERS_05})
PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_06=$(grep -oP '(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)' <<< ${PRETEND_PARAMETERS_06})
PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_07=$(grep -oP '(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)' <<< ${PRETEND_PARAMETERS_07})
PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_08=$(grep -oP '(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)' <<< ${PRETEND_PARAMETERS_08})
PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_09=$(grep -oP '(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)' <<< ${PRETEND_PARAMETERS_09})
PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_10=$(grep -oP '(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)' <<< ${PRETEND_PARAMETERS_10})
PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_11=$(grep -oP '(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)' <<< ${PRETEND_PARAMETERS_11})
PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_12=$(grep -oP '(?:-p|--project)[= ]\K(.*)(?= command1| command2| command3)' <<< ${PRETEND_PARAMETERS_12})
```

To see what those new variables hold:

```
echo ${PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_01}
echo ${PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_02}
echo ${PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_03}
echo ${PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_04}
echo ${PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_05}
echo ${PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_06}
echo ${PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_07}
echo ${PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_08}
echo ${PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_09}
echo ${PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_10}
echo ${PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_11}
echo ${PRETEND_PROJECT_PATH_12}
```

Comment: Using GNU `getopt` should be easier to pass command line options, including long options.

Comment: Can I guarantee that the host system would have getopt installed though?

Comment: If your server is running linux then `getopt` command is part of the util-linux-ng package which is by default installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bash` doesn't support `perl` regex capabilities that you are trying to use. If you need to stick to bash, check if following helps.

```
foo()
{
    echo "invoked with '$#' arguments: [$*]"
}

run_cli()
{
    path=
    # look for the value of -p/--project option
    for i in $(seq 1 $#); do
        if [[ "${!i}" =~ (-p|--project)(.*) ]]; then
            if [[ "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" == '' ]]; then
                i=$(( i + 1 ))
                path="${!i}"
            else
                path="${BASH_REMATCH[2]:1}"
            fi
            break
        fi
    done
    echo "path: [$path]"   # do what you want with the path
    foo "$@"    # call the other script here with the original set of arguments
}

# Usage examples
echo "- eg 1"
run_cli -p /path\ to\ data/path/to/data01 command1 --some-other=123

echo "- eg 2"
run_cli -p /path\ to\ data/path/to/data01 --some-other=123

echo "- eg 3"
run_cli -p=/path\ to\ data/path/to/data01 --some-other=123
```

Output:

```
- eg 1
path: [/path to data/path/to/data01]
invoked with '4' arguments: [-p /path to data/path/to/data01 command1 --some-other=123]

- eg 2
path: [/path to data/path/to/data01]
invoked with '3' arguments: [-p /path to data/path/to/data01 --some-other=123]

- eg 3
path: [/path to data/path/to/data01]
invoked with '2' arguments: [-p=/path to data/path/to/data01 --some-other=123]
```

Comment: I should have clarified that command* could  be one of any verb at all. I didn't mean to suggest that it would be of form, 'command*'

Comment: that is much more like it. Just a note, it currently only works with --parameter argument and not --parameter=argument

Comment: Perfect now, thank you! I find this a fascinating solution because it is a mix of very simple regex and vary simple shell scripting. Learned about BASH_REMATCH.